# How to create a Promise from the nested kotlin.js.Promise?

Tags: promise, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

`kotlin.js.Promise` has function `then` with this declaration:

```
open fun <S> then(
    onFulfilled: (T) -> S, 
    onRejected: (Throwable) -> S = definedExternally
): Promise<S>
```

I have two functions `a()` and `b()`. They both return a `Promise<Int>`. (They represent some requests to the server.) I need to combine them and create a new function like:

```
fun c(): Promise<Int> {
    a().then({
        b()
    })
}
```

But it is not possible, because return type is `Promise<Promise<Int>>` and not `Promise<Int>`.

I think this is possible in Javascript. How can I chain promises in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need an additional `Promise` for that, for example:

```
fun c(): Promise<Int> {
    return Promise({ resolve, reject ->
        a().then({
            b().then(resolve, reject);
        });
    })
}
```

the code above also can simplified by using [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) as below:

```
fun c() = Promise({ resolve, reject ->
    a().then({
        b().then(resolve, reject);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun c(): Promise<Int> {
    return a().then ({
        b().unsafeCast<Int>() 
        //Result of b is Promise<Int>, not Int, but then has bad type declaration
    })
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is actually useful in certain situations.
Basically in JS you can return a promise as a result of a promise, but in Kotlin the typings are screwed up since forever.